# Autocad C# - On Undo, the object Xdata becomes null

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin

This is in AutoCAD 2016

We have a problem with xdata being shown as null on Undo. We use Xdata to track the custom objects/blocks. We have started noticing this after we moved to AutoCAD2016.

I have included an example. Running the command **DrawRectangleWithXdata** will create a polyline with some xdata. You can examine this by running the command **ShowBlockXdata** after creating the object.

Now run Ctrl+Z to undo the DrawRectangleWithXdata command.
In the Database_ObjectErased event, you can see the Xdata is null.
Is there anyway I can get this?

Code below:

```
public partial class MainClass : Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.IExtensionApplication
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Document collection object
    /// </summary>
    DocumentCollection docCollection = null;
    public void Initialize()
    {
        docCollection = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager;
        docCollection.DocumentCreated += new DocumentCollectionEventHandler(docCollection_DocumentCreated);
    }

    public void Terminate()
    {

    }




    /// <summary>
    /// Executed whenever a new document is created/opened
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void docCollection_DocumentCreated(object sender, DocumentCollectionEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            e.Document.Database.ObjectModified += new ObjectEventHandler(Database_ObjectModified);
            e.Document.Database.ObjectErased += new ObjectErasedEventHandler(Database_ObjectErased);
            e.Document.Database.ObjectAppended += new ObjectEventHandler(Database_ObjectAppended);
        }
        catch { }             
    }

    private void Database_ObjectModified(object sender, ObjectEventArgs e)
    {
        object xdata = e.DBObject.XData;
    }

    private void Database_ObjectErased(object sender, ObjectErasedEventArgs e)
    {
        object xdata = e.DBObject.XData;
    }

    private void Database_ObjectAppended(object sender, ObjectEventArgs e)
    {
        object xdata = e.DBObject.XData;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This method registers the Application name for XData
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="regAppName">Application name to be registered</param>
    public void AddRegAppTableRecord(string regAppName)
    {
        Document doc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Editor ed = doc.Editor;
        Database db = doc.Database;

        using (Transaction tr = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            RegAppTable regAppTable = (RegAppTable)tr.GetObject(db.RegAppTableId, OpenMode.ForRead, false);
            if (!regAppTable.Has(regAppName))
            {
                regAppTable.UpgradeOpen();
                RegAppTableRecord ratr = new RegAppTableRecord();
                ratr.Name = regAppName;
                regAppTable.Add(ratr);
                tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(ratr, true);
            }
            tr.Commit();
        }
    }


    [CommandMethod("ShowBlockXdata", CommandFlags.UsePickSet)]
    public void ShowBlockXdata()
    {
        Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
        var ss = ed.SelectImplied();
        if (ss.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
        {
            using (Transaction tx = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
            {
                foreach (ObjectId objId in ss.Value.GetObjectIds())
                {
                    DBObject dbObject = tx.GetObject(objId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                    ed.WriteMessage(dbObject.XData.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }



    [CommandMethod("DrawRectangleWithXdata")]
    public void DrawRectangle()
    {
        //Polyline rectangle
        var p = new Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices.Polyline(4);
        p.AddVertexAt(0, new Point2d(0, 0), 0, 0, 0);
        p.AddVertexAt(0, new Point2d(10, 0), 0, 0, 0);
        p.AddVertexAt(0, new Point2d(0, 10), 0, 0, 0);
        p.AddVertexAt(0, new Point2d(10, 10), 0, 0, 0);

        Database db = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
        Document doc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Editor ed = doc.Editor;

        Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();

        using (tr)
        {
            BlockTableRecord btr = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(db.CurrentSpaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
            btr.AppendEntity(p);
            tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(p, true);

            AddRegAppTableRecord("MY_OBJECT");

            List<TypedValue> xdata = new List<TypedValue>();
            xdata.Add(new TypedValue(1001, "MY_OBJECT"));
            xdata.Add(new TypedValue(1070, 1234));

            ResultBuffer resBuffer = new ResultBuffer(xdata.ToArray());

            p.XData = resBuffer;

            tr.Commit();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put this block:

```
btr.AppendEntity(p);
tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(p, true);
```

after the line:

```
p.XData = resBuffer;
```

Like this :

```
BlockTableRecord btr = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(db.CurrentSpaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite);

AddRegAppTableRecord("MY_OBJECT");

List<TypedValue> xdata = new List<TypedValue>();
xdata.Add(new TypedValue(1001, "MY_OBJECT"));
xdata.Add(new TypedValue(1070, 1234));

ResultBuffer resBuffer = new ResultBuffer(xdata.ToArray());

p.XData = resBuffer;

btr.AppendEntity(p);
tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(p, true);

tr.Commit();
```

Comment: I separated the APPNAME registration into a new command method- 'RegisterAppId', ran it first and then ran the 'DrawRectangleWithXdata' command. So, Undo should not affect the first command method 'RegisterAppId'. But, still the Xdata is null.

Comment: You're right. I've updated my answer. It's not related to transaction, but where you append the entity.

Comment: Brilliant! Any explanation for this? It is definitely stored somewhere, because when I move it or delete it, the xData is available.

Comment: For some operations (like hatching for example), the order of method calls change the behavior. Here it seems that the XData is handled differently if it is set after the entity is appended to the database. It must comes from a change in the underlying code in AutoCAD 2016. May be @Augusto Goncalves can tell you more on this if he get in touch with the development team.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for UNDO/REDO you need to track Unappended and Reappended events.

Comment: I added a handler for the Unappended event and its being captured on Undo. However, the xData is still null